# Adding a data connection to SQL Server 2008 from VS 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Im trying to add a connection to a database in SQL Server 2008 using Visual Studio 2008. When testing the connection, it says that it is successful. However, once I said okay, it complains and say: "Cannot add data connection. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How do I go about adding a data connection to a SQL Server 2008 using Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: are you using visual studio server explorer or doing it from code? please add some details.

Answer (score 1):

Via code would be something like:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection([connectionString]);
conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is usually an indicator of not using the Keyword "New".